# dotnet - How to provide configuration when building swagger file locally

Tags: c#, swagger

When I try to generate local swagger file:

```
dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json Proj1.dll v1
```

Error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(Boolean overflow, String failureMessageID)
   at System.Guid.TryParseExactD(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at Basic.Configuration.SettingsExtension.ApplyLoggingConfiguration(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, String connectionStringKey) in C:\Users\person1\source\repos\Proj1\Proj1.Core\Basic.cs:line 383
```

Line 383 is where it tries to set `SomeKey` to a guid value, which is failing.

```
namespace Configuration
{
    public static class SettingsExtension
    {
        public static void ApplyLoggingConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, string connectionStringKey)
        {
            AppSettings.Core.SomeKey = new Guid(configuration["Guid1"]);
```

In my `appsettings.json` file, the key is there, so what else am I missing?

```
{
  "Guid1": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **missing 4 digit** in the **last** of `Guid1` string:

Guid format is:

**XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX**

*(8-4-4-4-12)*

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the problem, the other problem was, I have to add it to all appsettings.* files, which i missed.

Comment: Did you catch an exception or something like that?